# Formatting multi-line annotations in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Is there a way to customize the formatting of the continuation indent but only for annotations?

For example, IntelliJ (Android Studio) handles multi-line annotations like this:

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                BaseApplication.class,
                MyApplication.class,
                TestMyApplication.class
        },
        includes = { DomainModule.class }
)
public class AppModule {
   //...
}
```

I'd like it to be like so (only 4 spaces for continuous indent... though only for annotations).

```
@Module(
    injects = {
        BaseApplication.class,
        MyApplication.class,
        TestMyApplication.class
    },
    includes = { DomainModule.class }
)
public class AppModule {
   //...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, I do know that for JGrasp, all formatting is done (and is customizable) by the push of a button. I can't answer for IntelliJ (which is why I didn't put this as an answer), but for JGrasp, you would only need to change a few settings to make that possible

Comment: Code templates and formatter are for this.